# Why does spring beans runs default constructors even when parameters are provided?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring-bean

I am new to Spring. I created a class with default constructor and two arguments. I defined it in bean xml file. But still when I run the application, it runs the default constructor instead of the one with parameters. I could not find what am I doing wrong here. Here is the code:

***ConstructorArgsApp.java***

```
package com.kirancyrusken.springDemo;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class ConstructorArgsApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            //1. Create ApplicationContext
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans-cp.xml");

            //2 Create the bean
        Organization org = (Organization) ctx.getBean("myorg");

            //3. invoke the company slogan the bean
        org.corporateSlogan();

        System.out.println(org);

            //4. Close the application Context (container)
        ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) ctx).close();
    }
}
```

***Organization.java***

```
package com.kirancyrusken.springDemo;

public class Organization {

    private String companyName;
    private int yearOfIncorporation;

    public Organization() {
    }

    public Organization(String companyName, int yearOfIncorporation) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.yearOfIncorporation = yearOfIncorporation;
    }


    public void corporateSlogan() {
        String slogan = "We build the ultimate driving machines";
        System.out.println(slogan);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Organization [companyName=" + companyName + ", yearOfIncorporation=" + yearOfIncorporation + "]";
    }

}
```

***beans-cp.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


<bean id="myorg" 
    class="com.kirancyrusken.springDemo.Organization">
    <constructor-arg value="BMW"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="1929"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: try `<constructor-arg value="1929" type="int"></constructor-arg>`

Comment: @jens didn't work

Comment: Use the index attribute <constructor-arg value="BMW" index="0"></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg value="1929" index="1"></constructor-arg>

Comment: @mprabhat didn't work either

Comment: do you have duplicate beans-cp.xml somewhere ? I just ran your code and it prints correctly object with parameters. Moreover why do you say it doesnt work ? Infact index is not even required for it to work.

Comment: @mprabhat yeah. i guess that was the problem. I had beans.xml file on the resources folder and on the project root folder. I was configuring the one in the root folder so far. As I am using ClassPathXml, I am supposed to use the one in resources. I'd be careful next time. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, beans.xml under the directory resources are loaded. If the file is present anywhere else, it will not be loaded